# function() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given error for function calling

Tags: python, function

I'm a beginner Python programmer and I'm trying to understand functions properly. I want to understand why this function is not working and what the error message means.

```
def input():
    loop = True


    while loop == True:
        userInput = input('> ').lower()

        if userInput == 'help':
            help()

def main():
    input()

main()
```

This is a small section cut from my source code. 
I expect this to simply ask for user input and if it is 'help' run the help function which is defined elsewhere in my code. 
The problem is that I am receiving an error message that states the following:

> TypeError: input() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

I'm not exactly sure what a type error is or why this is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this issue because `input` is a built-in function in python. Kindly rename input to input_1 and it would work

Comment: `input` is not a keywork, that is why you can overwrite it. It is a built-in function.

Comment: @Netwave. Correct, I agree to you. Wrong word selection.

Answer (score 1):

You are redifining the `input` built-in funtion, simply rename yours:

```
def my_input():
    loop = True
    while loop == True:
        userInput = input('> ').lower()
        if userInput == 'help':
            help()

def main():
    my_input()

main()
```

Comment: wow ok i dont know how i didnt figure that out. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of your code you define `input` to be a function that takes no arguments. This shadows the builtin input function of python.

Answer (score 0):

You redefined python's built-in input function as a function which takes 0 arguments when you defined your input function. Consider using a different name for your function.

Answer (score 0):

The line `userInput = input('> ').lower()` calls the function `input` with the argument `'> '`

Answer (score 0):

Since `input` is a function already defined in python, it is throwing an error. Try

```
def input_func():
    loop = True


    while loop == True:
        userInput = input('> ').lower()

        if userInput == 'help':
            help()

def main():
    input_func()

main()
```